# why can’t we use any modifiers in float data type in c

Tags: c, linux, gcc, floating-point

why can’t we use any modifiers in float data type?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
    signed float a; 
    short float b; 
    return (0); 
}
```

If tries to use it ,the compiler gives compile time error.

```
error: both ‘signed’ and ‘float’ in declaration specifiers
signed float a; 

error: both ‘short’ and ‘float’ in declaration specifiers
short float b;
```

Why does compiler show this error?

Comment: Because a `float` is always signed, and has a fixed size.

Comment: (note: in a *freestanding environment* (e.g. embedded systems with no OS), where much of the language is *implementation defined*, you will see a short float, but understand that is not standard C) See [5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)

Comment: Study the C standard, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Because the language doesn't permit it.

There are exactly three floating-point types in C: `float`, `double`, and `long double`. There is no support for unsigned floating-point types, or for types other than those three. (Implementations can provide such types as extensions.)

`signed`, `unsigned`, and `short` are not qualifiers that can be applied arbitrarily. They exist only as part of the syntax of the names of predefined integer types. The type specifiers are defined in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.7.2.

Apparently some compilers do support `short float` as a 16-bit floating-point type, but it's non-standard.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds okay in theory, but in practice those things don't really work.

The way floats are laid out in memory, they already have a dedicated bit for sign so `float` essentially already is a `signed float`.

A short float doesn't have enough room to hold much meaningful information. If we were to assume a `short float` has 16 bits of memory then after the sign bit, we would barely have enough bits for one or two digits of precision and a highly limited exponent.

If memory is critical then you should instead consider using a fixed-point number instead of a **float**ing-point number. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: IEEE754 does have a 16-bit floating point format that would make sense to call `short float` in an environment that provides it... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format 5 bits for exponent, 11 for significand.